# JDBC Inconsistent with LIKE

Tags: jdbc, sql-like

Im new with JDBC, and while executing some query i get a result that is inconsistent.

If i execute this query in sql developer (connected to a Oracle DB) i get 4 results

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable1 some1 
JOIN someTable2 some2 on (some1.some_id= some2.other_id)
WHERE some2.some_date LIKE '01/01/01' OR some2.some_date IS NULL
```

Then, i load this same query from a properties file in java and execute the query and get 0 results... anyone know why this is happening? I first suspect of the single quotes in the propertie value but i dont know...

Thanks in advance and excuse my poor english! :)

Comment: What is the type of the "some_date" column?

Comment: The type is DATE as far as i know...

Comment: The string is '01/01/01' is probably interpreted differently because of different Locale / Time settings. Use to_date with a specific format instead. Also, why do you use LIKE to compare the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query doesn't contain any special characters which could confuse Java, the properties loader or JDBC, so you should get exactly the same results in SQL Developer and with JDBC.

In fact, SQL Developer is written in Java, so it is using JDBC to execute the queries.

Print the query to the console before you execute it to make 100% sure the code executes the query that you have in mind.

Next, you should check the type of `some_date`. `LIKE` is only defined for string types (`VARCHAR` and similar), not for date/time types.

Oracle has a set of helper functions to build queries for date/time types, for example:

```
some_date = to_date( '01/01/2001','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

or

```
TRUNC(some_date, 'DAY') = to_date( '01/01/2001','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

The second query strips hours, minutes, seconds, etc. from the column and will compare only days, months and years.

Note: Always use 4-digit years to avoid all kinds of odd problems.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses :) I tried to change my query without the LIKE operator but in this way i get 0 results when i execute it on sql developer too.. :( and in fact there are "01/01/01" dates stored

Comment: If the datatype is `DATE`, then it is not stored like `01/01/01`, that is just presentation that depends on the locale of server and/or client.

Comment: Sorry, the date format was wrong (`01` asks for `mm` instead of `mmm`). Try again, please.

Comment: Yes, i realized it should be that way.. but it didnt work anyway :( i dont understand why it only works with "LIKE". Mark, how should i compare dates then, if it is just a presentation issue??

Comment: Can you please add the table's DDL to the question? The column some_date is enough.

Comment: The create table for that field is: "SOME_DATE" DATE

Comment: In that case, `some_date = to_date( '01/01/01','mm/dd/yy')` is correct. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Hi! It worked! :) thank you Aaron. I had to change to to_date( '01/01/01','mm/dd/yyyy') with full year at the end.. i dont know why when i look at dates in the tables they are only with two digits in the year... but changing that it all worked! thank you all! :)

Comment: That's probably because of the default date formatter configured in the preferences of SQL Developer.